Trying to understand iMac M1 local HD odd disk usage
In my Home directory on the M1 I have a directory 'Containers' which is 213GB, which seems to be ALL in Messages/Data/tmp/com.apple.MobileSMSTemporaryItems/!
There are 2 more directories in there both with ~100GB:

LinkedFiles/
Media/

Each of these has several hundred directories (mostly empty). In Media/ the largest one contains

Lord Of The Rings and The Hobbit 2001-2014

With all 6 episodes of the series.
No idea why these are in there but I'm very tempted to delete them.
Would this have undesireable effects on my system?

Go ahead and delete them. They're in a /tmp/ direceto

My thinking too. Thanks for confirming.

Wow! My comment got all munged up! ... directory, so at some point the files were destined to be deleted anyway, but the process failed, or never was initiated. You could always mv the files to an external drive if you want to keep the LOTR video files, especially if they are playable.
